# rsync using only spare bandwidth?

Tags: linux, rsync, bandwidth

My scenario:

- Several rural schools
- Every school:

  - One linux server
  - Limited bandwidth (shared with all school PCs)
  - Electricity not guaranteed (last to leave the school could cut all electricity)
  - Geographically disperse

I have to backup all school linux servers to a central server.

Method of backup chosen: `rsync` (minimizes bandwidth usage)

Problem: Backup could degrade the network

First approximation: Using `--bwlimit=RATE` parameter that limits socket I/O bandwidth. But it's a fixed amount, don't take advantage free network time and stands in the way in crowded network time.

Question: Any way to make rsync to use only spare bandwidth? maybe mark its traffic as low priority somehow?

Comment: That's another reason why many organisation have a segregated back-up network :) If you're running the actual rsync protocol then some form of QoS on the network layer isn't that difficult. If encapsulating rsync in SSH that might be slightly less trivial.

Comment: A bit lost on QoS. Any hint in how to shape this kind of traffic?

Comment: @HBruijn Can't be too difficult. The ssh client can be invoked with `ssh -o IPQoS=0` or some other number to chose the QoS to use.

Answer (score 0):

Does your network support QoS? If it does you should use the right IP TOS field for rsync traffic. You can use Linux `tc` command for that.

Also there are standard classification [scheme](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.qdisc.classless.html) . You can mark rsync traffic for example with 0 and watch the difference.

Comment: It's not enough to mark only, it should be marked _and_ prioritized.

Comment: Seems that 0 is for normal traffic (normal as no QoS involved?) and other numbers for higher priority traffic. No lower priority traffic (explicitly) on this table.
Will 0 be less than other computer on the LAN traffic?

Comment: In theory on Linux system - yes. On other it may depends. You can prioritize traffic on your Linux machines (as say drookie) and it may help you ( but only for outbound traffic ).